# What does ':' mean at the end of a PHP 'if' statement?

Tags: php

What does `:` at the end of the expression mean?

```
<?
if(!validateName($_POST['name'])):
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Colon (:) operator mostly used in embedded coding of php and html.

Using this operator you can avoid use of curly brace. This operator reduce complexity in embedded coding. You can use this(:) operator with if, while, for, foreach and more...

Without (:) operator

```
<body>
<?php if(true){ ?>
<span>This is just test</span>
<?php } ?>
</body>
```

With (:) operator

```
<body>
<?php if(true): ?>
<span>This is just test</span>
<?php endif; ?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

> PHP offers an alternative syntax for some of its control structures; namely, if, while, for, foreach, and switch. In each case, the basic form of the alternate syntax is to change the opening brace to a colon (:) and the closing brace to endif;, endwhile;, endfor;, endforeach;, or endswitch;, respectively.

```
<?php if ($a == 5): ?>
A is equal to 5
<?php endif; ?>
```

ref: [Alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)

Answer (score 0):

This ':' operator after the `if()` statement is a multi-line if statement essentially. It will be terminated after some code (most likely in a language other than PHP) by `<? endif ?>`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the endif syntax (http://www.phpbuilder.com/manual/migration.if-endif.php) and is used like this:

```
<?
if(!validateName($_POST['name'])):
    echo "Something";
endif;
?>
```

This style is useful in php scripts when interlated with Javascript and HTML.